# How do I create a HUD on top of my Scenekit.scene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, hud, scenekit

I'm experimenting with Swift and Scenekit.
Building a Mac OS X app.
It seems quite easy to get a 3d-scene working.
But what is scene without some kind of 2D hi-score, radar display, speed indicator, etc?
I would expect a SpriteKit-scene to seamlessly integrate into a SceneView but I don't find the documentation very clear about this..

The most obvious and only way I can think of is to position a SKView over a SceneView and render each separately.
But is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Look at the sample code form WWDC 14. It displays a HUD using Sprite Kit on top of Scene Kit.

Answer (score 12):

try

```
scnView.overlaySKScene = aSKScene;
```

(see SCNSceneRenderer.h)
This is the recommended way. An alternative way is to make the SCNView layer backed and add child views or layers (but this is less efficient).

Comment: +1 :) You can find more info in [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNSceneRenderer_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/SCNSceneRenderer/overlaySKScene) and in the [Bananas](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/Bananas/Introduction/Intro.html) and [Vehicle](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/SceneKitVehicle/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code projects. Another benefit of SK overlays is you can make your HUD cross platform, instead of using UIKit on iOS and AppKit on OS X.

Comment: I checked out the Bananas sample project. It fails to run. Can you run the code on 10.9.3? Does swift have an 'overlaySKScene' equivalent?

Comment: SceneKit/SpriteKit integration is a 10.10 feature, as are some of the other features you see in Bananas. That project does have an iOS target, though, so you can also try running it on an iOS 8 beta device.

Answer (score 7):

To create a HUD, do something like the following:

```
// SKContainerOverlay is a class which inherits from SKScene

    SKContainerOverlay *skContainerOverlay = [[SKContainerOverlay alloc] initWithSize:self.sceneView.bounds.size];
    self.sceneView.overlaySKScene = skContainerOverlay;
    self.sceneView.overlaySKScene.hidden = NO;
    self.sceneView.overlaySKScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeResizeFill; // Make sure SKScene bounds are the same as our SCNScene
    self.sceneView.overlaySKScene.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

You can create all your `SKLabelNode` objects inside the custom `SKContainerOverlay` class.

Comment: Thank you for providing a real answer instead of pointing to the documentation or sample apps.

Answer (score 2):

As @Toyos said above, you can use

```
scnView.overlaySKScene = aSKScene
```

to superimpose the SKScene on your SCNView.

However, when I tried this in Swift, I found that the `overlaySKScene` property only becomes visible if you include an `import SpriteKit` statement.

Answer (score 0):

As @Toyos answered, it is simple to day using `scnView.overlaySKScene`. If you want an example you can check how Apple did it in their [Bananas demo](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/Bananas/Introduction/Intro.html).