# How can I overlay a SKScene over a SCNScene in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, scenekit

There are some overlay tutorials on the Internet, all using 
`overlaySKScene` at some point.

That is somehow not possible in my project, as (I guess) my view does not use the constructor of `SCNView` at any point (which `overlaySKScene` is a part of).

In the ViewController's viewDidLoad, basically only the MainScene is created:

```
viewDidLoad() {
self.sceneView = MainScene(view: self.view)) }
```

...which goes here (note: SCNScene instead of SCNView):

```
class MainScene: SCNScene, SCNPhysicsContactDelegate {...
init(view:UIView) {
scnView = view as! SCNView
super.init()
scnView.scene = self; (...) }
```

The scene is perfectly created, I would now like to overlay a SKScene. Does anyone know how?

Comment: scenes and views are two different things,  self.sceneView should not = MainScene

Comment: if overlaySKScene is not working, it is because you did not import SpriteKit into your MainScene code

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The SpriteKit overlay goes on the SceneKit view, not on the SceneKit scene. This is a bit confusing because you're overlaying a scene on a view.

I see several possible error sources:

```
self.sceneView = MainScene(view: self.view))
```

as defined returns an `SCNScene`. You're assigning that to a property that expects an `SCNView`.

The line

```
scnView = view as! SCNView
```

will crash unless `view` returns a properly connected `SCNView` instance. But the `init` definition you've written expects a `UIView`.

Somewhere, you need to have your view be an `SCNView`. That view, because it conforms to protocol `SCNSceneRenderer`, will have an `overlaySKScene` property on it (`overlaySKScene` comes from that protocol, not from `SCNView`). That's where you can assign your `SKScene` instance.

If you have done that, then your code would look something like

```
scnView.scene = self 
scnView.overlaySKScene = theSKScene
```

I have a simple example of an `SKScene` overlaid on an `SCNView` at https://github.com/halmueller/ImmersiveInterfaces/tree/master/Tracking%20Overlay

See also [How do I create a HUD on top of my Scenekit.scene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24419193/how-do-i-create-a-hud-on-top-of-my-scenekit-scene).

Comment: Thanks for the great example!! But how to add more than one overlay into scene? In the provided sample only one overlay is added. How to reuse the same InformationOverlayScene provided in the provided example(https://github.com/halmueller/ImmersiveInterfaces/tree/master/Tracking%20Overlay) for multiple texts and for multiple nodes?

Comment: The overlay scene can be as complex as you like. If you think you need multiple scenes, that deserves its own question.