# How can I add UIView fixed elements above the ARkit scene

Tags: swift, arkit

I want to add 4 buttons that will appears all the time in the user screen. I tried to add them above the AR view but it didn't work

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Please show us what you've tried so far (a code snippet).  Here's some help with formatting your post https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add four buttons from object library on an **ARSCNView** . It's as simple as adding buttons to a UIView just drag and drop and connect **IBActions** and **IBOutlets** as per the requirement. For example 
[image: See this screenshot i have added two buttons above the scene view and attached their IBAction]

Then just add IBAction to the ViewController file and it will definitely work.

```
@IBAction func add(_ sender: Any) {
    // do your stuff
 }
 @IBAction func reset(_ sender: Any) {
    // do your stuff
 }
```

Answer (score -3):

You have to use overlaySKScene attribute of the scene, which is an SKScene.
overlaySKScene is an attribute of the scnView.
Check the doc [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1524051-overlayskscene) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34584257/how-can-i-overlay-a-skscene-over-a-scnscene-in-swift)