# How can I pick item from collectionView and add it to SCNScene?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, augmented-reality, arkit

I am working with SceneKit and ARKit. I have made a `collectionView` with an array of emoji's. Now I want the user to be able to select the emoji from `collectionView` and when he/she touches the screen that selected emoji will be placed in 3D.

How can I do that? I think I have to create a function for the Node, but still my idea is blurry in the mind and I am not very much clear.

Answer (score 0):

As far as any emoji is a 2D element, it's better to use a SpriteKit framework to upload them, not a SceneKit. But, of course, you might choose a SceneKit as well. So, there are two ways you can work with emojis in ARKit:

- **Using SpriteKit**. In that case all the 2D sprites you spawn in ARSKView are always face the camera. So, if the camera moves around a definite point of real scene, all the sprites are rotates about their pivot point facing a camera.
- **Using SceneKit**. In ARSCNView you can use all your sprites as a texture for 3D geometry. This texture could be for a plane, cube, sphere, or any custom model, it's up to you. To make, for example, a plane (with emojis texture on it) to face a camera use [SCNBillboardConstraint](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnbillboardconstraint) constraint.

Here's how you code in `ViewController` might look like:

```
// Element's index coming from `collectionView`
var i: Int = 0

func view(_ view: ARSKView, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SKNode? {
    let emojiArray = ["","","","",""]
    let emojiNode = SKLabelNode(text: emojiArray[i])           
    emojiNode.horizontalAlignmentMode = .center
    emojiNode.verticalAlignmentMode = .center
    return emojiNode
}
```

...and in `Scene.swift` file:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let sceneView = self.view as? ARSKView else { return }

    if let currentFrame = sceneView.session.currentFrame {
        var translation = matrix_identity_float4x4
        translation.columns.3.z = -0.75               // 75 cm from camera
        let transform = simd_mul(currentFrame.camera.transform, translation)
        let anchor = ARAnchor(transform: transform)
        sceneView.session.add(anchor: anchor)
    }
}
```

Or, if you use hit-testing, your code might look like this:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let sceneView = self.view as? ARSKView else { return }

    if let touchLocation = touches.first?.location(in: sceneView) {
        if let hit = sceneView.hitTest(touchLocation, types: .featurePoint).first {
            sceneView.session.add(anchor: ARAnchor(transform: hit.worldTransform))
        }
    }
}
```

If you'd like to create an `UICollectionView` overlay containing emojis to choose from, read [the following post](https://www.raywenderlich.com/527-custom-uicollectionviewlayout-tutorial-with-parallax).

If you'd like to create an `SKView` overlay, containing emojis to choose from, read [the following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34584257/how-can-i-overlay-a-skscene-over-a-scnscene-in-swift).

Comment: ok so does it mean SCNnode doesn't support the 2D format. I understand this method but how to pass it to collection view i want the node to be selected from collection view